# SQL Server 2008 - Restore Database With RESTART

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore a database from a backup file on a SQL Server 2008 instance using the following SQL command:

```
BEGIN 
    RESTORE DATABASE [MyDataBase] 
    FROM DISK=@db_location 
    WITH STATS=5, 
    FILE=1, 
    MOVE @db_OldName TO @db_NewFile, 
    MOVE @db_OldLogName TO @db_NewLogFile, 
    NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, RESTART, RECOVERY 
END
```

and it fails with the following error:

> Msg 3264, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   The operation did not proceed far
>   enough to allow RESTART. Reissue the
>   statement without the RESTART
>   qualifier. Msg 3013, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 19 RESTORE DATABASE is
>   terminating abnormally.

If I do not use the RESTART option the backup is successful. On SQL Server 2005 it works even with the RESTART parameter.

Since the SQL command is issued by a program I cannot change it. Is there a way to work around this issues on SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has this ever worked?

RESTART is only specified when you want to [continue an interrupted restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187851.aspx).
If you can't change the SQL, then you can only somehow break a first restore to generate an error condition.

Because of this, you can't be sure that it's the same on SQL 2005 unless it happens every time. Or they changed behaviour.